# JPanel doesn't call addLayoutComponent() of custom LayoutManager

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I need to create a custom LayoutManager to be used by a JPanel.

However, when I add a Component to the JPanel, the JPanel doesn't call the addLayoutComponent() method of my custom LayoutManager, even though it should:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/custom.html

(It does call layoutContainer(), as expected)

Hopefully, someone can tell me what I am doing wrong.
How do I get the JPanel to call addLayoutComponent()?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        createAndShowGUI();
    }



    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JButton button = new JButton("Test");
        button.setBounds(64, 64, 128, 64);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new CustomLayoutManager());

        //FIXME: Missing call to CustomLayoutManager.addLayoutComponent()
        panel.add(button); 

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.toFront();
    }



    public static class CustomLayoutManager implements LayoutManager
    {
        public void addLayoutComponent(String name, Component comp)
        {
            System.out.println("addLayoutComponent");
        }

        public void layoutContainer(Container parent)
        {
            System.out.println("layoutContainer");
        }

        public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container parent)
        {
            System.out.println("minimumLayoutSize");
            return new Dimension();
        }

        public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container parent)
        {
            System.out.println("preferredLayoutSize");
            return new Dimension();
        }

        public void removeLayoutComponent(Component comp)
        {
            System.out.println("removeLayoutComponent");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I get the JPanel to call addLayoutComponent()?

It would only invoke this method if your layout manager uses constraints

```
panel.add(button);
```

Try:

```
panel.add("some constraint value", button);
```

This method is intended to be used to pass constraints to the layout manager. I think BorderLayout is the only layout manager that might have used this. However it generally should not be used anymore.  Instead LayoutManager2 uses:

```
public void addLayoutComponent(Component component, Object constraint)
```

which allows you to pass any Object as a constraint.

Comment: Many thanks for this concise answer.
It seems the only "stable" way to go is to implement LayoutManager2.  With Container.add(Component component, Object constraint), the LayoutManager2.addLayoutComponent(Component component, Object constraint) method is called, as required.

Comment: question is there some differencies between constraint and putProperty isn't same (I used for DocumentListener), sure maybe my question is out of reality (lack of knowledges about...) +1

Comment: @mKorbel, A constraint is an Object used by layout managers to help control the layout of the components. See the GridBagLayout and GridBagConstraints for an example of how a constraint can be use. I'm not sure where putProperty() is used in a DocumentListener or LayoutManager so I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I means put property for adding/removing/notify Listeners on Runtime f.e. `sheduleNoDays.getDocument().addDocumentListener(documentListener); ` then `sheduleNoDays.getDocument().putProperty("name", "sheduleNoDays");`

Comment: You are adding a custom property to the Document. It has nothing to do with a DocumentListener. Any class that has access to the Document has access to the property. This is similiar to a constraint in that it provides more information about the Document that allows you change the way the Document is rendered or used.